# Como ler arquivo CSV do sdcard?

Tags: android, inputstream

Atualmente eu leio um arquivo `csv` da pasta `assets` com o código a seguir:

```
    String arquivoCSV = "clientes.csv";
    AssetManager manager = context.getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    try{
        inputStream = manager.open(arquivoCSV);
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```

Porém eu preciso atualizar esse arquivo constantemente, e pela pasta assets não é possível, preciso ler o arquivoCSV do sdcard, alguém tem alguma idéia de como fazer?

Utilizei o código, porém agora ele não identifica nenhuma linha, segue o código:

```
    File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(path, "/produtos.csv");
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
    String line = "";
    conn.beginTransaction();
    conn.delete("PRODUTOS", "1", null);
        try{

            while ((line = buffer.readLine())!= null){
                String[] colunas = line.split(",");
                    if (colunas.length != 6){
                        Log.d("CSVParder","Ignorando linhas ruins");
                        continue;
                    }
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put("COD_PRODUTO",colunas[0].trim());
                cv.put("NOME",colunas[1].trim());
                cv.put("DESCR",colunas[2].trim());
                cv.put("GRUPO",colunas[3].trim());
                cv.put("SUBGRUPO",colunas[4].trim());
                cv.put("MEDIDA",colunas[5].trim());

                conn.insert("PRODUTOS",null,cv);

            }

        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    conn.setTransactionSuccessful();
    conn.endTransaction();
    Toast.makeText(context,"Produtos atualizados com sucesso!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Tenta Alterar o seu while para este     while ((line = buffer.readLine())!= -1) {
// intrução }     Creio que funcione

Comment: Não tem como, String comparar com int, na verdade acho q não está conseguindo ler nenhuma linha pois no log está dando muitas CSVParder","Ignorando linhas ruins" e o bd está vazio!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá,
Basta voce criar um tipo File e depois passa-lo ao FileInputStream

**Desta forma:**

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(path, "path/clientes.cvs");
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Comment: Utilizei o código, porém agora ele não identifica nenhuma linha, segue o código:

Answer (score 1):

Funcionou perfeitamente, meu csv que estava corrompido. Obrigado!

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(path, "/produtos.csv");
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
String line = "";
conn.beginTransaction();
conn.delete("PRODUTOS", "1", null);
    try{

        while ((line = buffer.readLine())!= null){
            String[] colunas = line.split(",");
                if (colunas.length != 6){
                    Log.d("CSVParder","Ignorando linhas ruins");
                    continue;
                }
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("COD_PRODUTO",colunas[0].trim());
            cv.put("NOME",colunas[1].trim());
            cv.put("DESCR",colunas[2].trim());
            cv.put("GRUPO",colunas[3].trim());
            cv.put("SUBGRUPO",colunas[4].trim());
            cv.put("MEDIDA",colunas[5].trim());

            conn.insert("PRODUTOS",null,cv);

        }

    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
conn.setTransactionSuccessful();
conn.endTransaction();
Toast.makeText(context,"Produtos atualizados com sucesso!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Se possível marque como respondido para fechar o tópico, e dar uma ajuda ;)